# sending a GET request with query String

Tags: java, get, request

q4: Write a public static method named q4 that takes an int as a parameter and returns an 
int. The returned int will be the response from the server after sending a GET request to 
the url "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/type-two" with a query String containing 
"powerful" with value 23, and "silver" with value 56 as well as "input" with a value equal 
to the int from the input of this method. The response from the server will be a String 
 that is a well-formed int.

My autoLab is giving me this error

```
{"correct":false,"feedback":"On input: [2]\nGrader expected: 548\nYour method returned: -1"}
```

This is my code

```
public static int q4(int n)
        {
            String url = "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/type-two";
             String response = "";

            try{
                response = Request.Get(url)
                        .setHeader("powerful", "23")
                        .setHeader("silver", "56")
                        .setHeader("input", String.valueOf(n))
                        .execute().returnContent().asString();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return Integer.parseInt(response);
        }
```

Comment: You are sending your parameters as headers, not as part of the query string.

Comment: should i do something like this    .getQueryString("focus", "56")

Comment: No - simply include your GET parameters in the URL.  Here's a great tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: is this what i should do?                                                                    String url = "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/type-two"+ request.getQueryString("oxygen", "38")+ request.getQueryString("streak", "33") + request.getQueryString("powerful", "37") +  request.getQueryString("input", String.valueOf(n));

Comment: Q: Did you read the link? Q: Did you resolve the problem?  Q: Do you now understand that "GET" query strings are in the form `http://myhost/folder/file.html?name1=value1&name2=value2`

Comment: I didnt understand too much from the link , it seemed confusing but I did find notes that helped me understand. Thanks